# Getting Error in Telerik Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is my first application in Telerik Kendo UI. I Write the following code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("MyBirthDay").Value(DateTime.Today))
```

i got this Error

```
Unable to copy file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET MVC Q3 2013\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc3\Kendo.Mvc.xml" to "bin\Kendo.Mvc.xml". Access to the path 'bin\Kendo.Mvc.xml' is denied.    Kendo2
```

And

```
Unable to copy file "c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyFirstKendo\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.xml" to "bin\System.Web.Mvc.xml". Access to the path 'bin\System.Web.Mvc.xml' is denied.  Kendo2
```

This is my full code

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("MyBirthDay").Value(DateTime.Today))
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unchecked **Read-only** of my project **bin** folder but it give same error after sometime.

For Resolve this error need go **lib** folder in your project then **KENDOUIMVC** folder then **2013.3.1324.340** folder. In that have **Kendo.Mvc XML file**, right click on it and unchecked **Read-Only**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder of **bin** of your application and **right click** on **bin** folder and uncheck **Read-Only**. Currently your folder is **read-only**